# How to make a DELETE link to a rails resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I want to make a DELETE link in rails, I write the following code (in this example case to delete a user session in Devise):

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

That will turn into the following HTML:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a>
```

Works great, except I can't simply put that HTML into a static HTML page. It will simply do a GET request. I assume Rails includes some standard Javascript to turn the above link to one that actually does a DELETE request. So what's the proper way to have a link on a static HTML page to a Rails resource that does a DELETE action? Should I find and grab that Javascript Rails includes in all webpages that does this? Is there a better way?

Comment: You are starting from the wrong point. Destructive operations such as DELETE shouldn't be displayed as links in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't send a `DELETE` request with an anchor link, unfortunately - a traditional anchor link will only send a `GET` request. Actually, you can't really send a true `DELETE` request at all. If you want to make a delete link, without javascript, the solution is fairly easy. Check out *2.4 How do forms with PUT or DELETE methods work?* in the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). Basically, you can simply create a form that submits to the url of your resource, with a method of `delete`. It's pretty simple, and you don't need to rely on javascript to get the job done. Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I can't have a normal link as a post button to a form though.. I'd think the styling would have to be pretty tricky to look like a link.

Comment: I think it's pretty common to use selective portions of rails.js, but in this case, you could just add an onclick handler to the anchor to submit the form, turning it into an easy 1-liner, if you're opposed to using rails.js.

Comment: To be honest, with caching and the asset pipeline, including rails.js doesn't really seem to be an unnecessarily large addition. Including it will also make the app behave more closely to how future maintainers of the app would expect it to behave (so if they go to use another element of rails.js, they won't find it missing).

Comment: What I think I was hoping for was a rails_delete_link.js type file that would be maintained by the rails project and I could include just that. But including the whole rails.js seems to be the next best thing.

Answer (score 3):

Rails uses JavaScript to handle `delete` links.

It creates a invisible form, and submits it when you click a link that has a `data-method` attribute of `"delete"`

Have a look at `handleMethod` in https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Maybe your delete links in your static pages will just work when you include `rails.js` (if you are using jQuery).
If not, you can build a form as it is done in `handleMethod` on your own.

Comment: it seems like overkill to include the whole rails.js if I just want DELETE links. I could just copy that javascript out of it or insert that whole form and then use Javascript to submit that form when the link is clicked... Seems like Rails should come with a little Javascript snippet that handles this kind of thing in non-Rails webpages.

Comment: Of course there are different ways to handle this. You could also include forms instead of links and all the JavaScript, and style the submit button to have it look like a regular link.

Answer (score 3):

Since some of my colleagues are working on a native app where the user may not have the JavaScript enabled on their browsers, in such cases the delete link won't work and we would get the show page instead of delete....So if you are unsure whether the user may or or may not have the JS enabled on its browser, you can always generate a route with GET or POST method to the delete action of your controller...This approach would work for the static HTML pages also..

Comment: That violates REST protocols... I'd rather assume they have JS enabled.

Comment: I know that it is against the protocols of REST but I am sharing my experience of how this can be accomplished in the absence of JS or any other client side scripting support...Imagine your app running on Windows 98 or NT and they still haven't seen the cool quotient of JQuery and other scripts...

Comment: @at it doesn't matter since REST protocols can't be followed by nowadays browsers. I don't understand why the default scaffolding of Rails would propose a solution where you have to have javascript enabled.